# how do i keep transparency in a logo made with inkscape when uploading it to facebook

Tags: inkscape, transparency, png

I created a logo for a customer using inkscape and exported it as a .PNG image. I can use it in Word or Publisher no problem with a transparent background, but my customer said it had a solid background when he uploaded it to facebook. 
How do i keep the transparency?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, you can't.

Facebook compresses and converts to JPG (doesn't allow transparency).